# Как отменять только некоторые Task'и?

Tags: c#, task

Вот допустим у меня есть несколько задач, некоторые из которых я хочу отменить (но не все). Я использую токен отмены и всё прекрасно.

```
class ClassWithToken
{
    private CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource;
    public async void StartTask(Action aciton)
    {
        using(_cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource())
        {
            await Task.Run(aciton, _cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        }
    }
    public void Stop()
    {
        _cancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();
    }
}
```

Пока не появляется еще несколько `Task`-ов. Т.к у меня их несколько, мне что, под каждый `Task` делать отдельный токен чтобы потом отменить? Полагаю, это неправильно. Так как же правильно отменять только некоторые задачи, а не все подряд?

```
private CancellationTokenSource _cts1;
public async void StartTask(Action aciton)
{
    using (_cts1 = new CancellationTokenSource())
    {
        await Task.Run(aciton, _cts1.Token);
    }
}
public void Stop()
{
    _cts1?.Cancel();
}


private CancellationTokenSource _cts2;
public async void StartTask(Action aciton)
{
    using (_cts2 = new CancellationTokenSource())
    {
        await Task.Run(aciton, _cts2.Token);
    }
}
public void Stop()
{
    _cts2?.Cancel();
}
```

Comment: "Полагаю, это неправильно" - нет. это правильно. CancellationToken отменяет все задачи, что за ним следять. Ну и что с того, что это бывает одна задача.

Comment: Мне под каждую делать новое поле `CancellationTokenSource`? Разве нет способа как-то автоматизировать этот способ?

Comment: Угу. Количество CancellationTokenSource будет такое, сколько нужно раздельных отмен. Как их сопоставлять с тасками...как удобнее, хоть словарь task -> CancellationTokenSource

Comment: @vitidev Если у вас есть какой-нибудь способ которым вы пользуетесь, может поделитесь им со мной и с коммьюнити опубликовав ответ?

Comment: Да я даже не понимаю проблемы. Вас просто смущает необходимость заводить дублирующие объекты, а я вообще не вижу тут проблем. Если я что-то запускаю, что хочу отменить, то я просто сохраняю что-то, у чего могу дернуть .Cancel(). Таска ли это (в других языках) или токен - нет никакой разницы. Если бы в языке не было CancellationTokenSource, а можно было бы прямо отменять таски, то код был бы идентичен. У вас просто мозг ломает, что нужно наплодить море "дублирующих объектов", но на самом деле разницы нет

Comment: @vitidev вы правы про то дублирующиеся объекты. Спасибо вам!!

Comment: Учтите, что перегрузка `Task.Run(Action, CancellationToken)` не передаёт токен в action. Этот метод позволит лишь отменить _запуск_ задачи, но не прервать её.